# Spring-Kafka request/reply listener timeout

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring-Kafka and using request/reply templates. I am noticing that after awhile I encounter timeouts when one service calls the other. The only way this seems to resolve is when I change topic name from request1, reply1 to request2, reply2 and redeploy both sides.... What am I missing in the configuration of the listener and or requester side? It seems the after a period of time it goes stale

Comment: It does not work to just redeploy the service. I do need to change the topic names for some reason .. strange but true.

Comment: There is nothing in the framework that would cause this behavior, and I can't think of any scenario where that might happen; you need to show your code and configuration; even better if you can provide a small, complete, sample that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Its kind of proprietary stuff but yes it happens periodically. I will try to update

Comment: When it happens, I suggest you explore the comsumer group information with `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` - it will show you the relationships between your consumers and their topics.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: So it turned out when that responding handler was making a second call that was causing the timeout.  Is there a setting that will publish/log performance data Spring-Kafka calls. I am measuring about 50 millis for each inter service call.